# how to update webscraped data with bs4 and requests in python

Tags: python

I'm making a Twitter bot that tweets the price of dogecoin every hour. but I noticed that the data only updates when I close the program and then run it again. is there any way to make it refresh while the script is constantly running?

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   
r = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DOGE-USD/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,features="html.parser")
dogevalue =  soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" }).text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have the program running with a `while True:` around it, and just delay the next request, using the `time` module's `sleep` function, by a certain amount of time (FYI, `sleep`'s parameter is in seconds). Here's an example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

REFRESH_INTERVAL_S = 5# 5 minutes

while True:

  r = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DOGE-USD/")
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,features="html.parser")
  dogevalue = soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" }).text

  # do what you want to the dogevalue here

  time.sleep(REFRESH_INTERVAL_S)
```

Comment: time.sleep takes time to sleep in seconds as its argument

Comment: fixed it, thanks, got confused with another lang